# to pass the value retrieved from a database to the be used in other subsequent forms

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am doing a project with the help of java,servlets and tomcat apache. First i have created a form for user login(1st form), upon submitting this, we are asked to input a phone number(2nd form) . This number i have retrieved using getParameter in the third form. But again after submitting the 3rd form,i need the phone number to be displayed in the fourth form(which is generated upon submitting the 3rd form). i tried using input tag with hidden attribute , but when i passed its value as request.getParameter, its displaying  request.getParameter but not the number. Hw can i do it. I am not using jsp. I want to do directly with java and servlet.

Comment: It would be helpful to the community if you post the 3rd and 4th forms you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Java Web Development.

I think you are in need to learn of [Session](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/Session.html) and Session Handling in java web applications.

In the *3rd form* when you retrieve the `phoneNumber` store it in a session object as:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("phone", phoneNumber); // pair of String=key and Object=value
```

Now in *4th form* you can get the phone number as:

```
Object phoneNumber = request.getSession().getAttribute("phone");
session.invalidate(); //clear-up current session
```

*Parse* this `phoneNumber` in whatever form you want.

Comment: If you have a parameter that you can pass on request, then do it by request, no need to overload the session.

Comment: I point out `session` because he needs `phone number` from _2nd form_ to _4th form_, here session would be easier to implement.

Comment: Easier to implement vs better performance, I'll always choose better performance.

Comment: I don't think a two-way request will going to be better than session here? and if it is please do provide it, i would love to learn new thing.. :)

Comment: That's why I've asked OP to show his/her form code, so it would be easier to check where the error could be.

Comment: THANK YOU, THAT WAS VERY HELPFUL...I EVEN GOT IT BY REQUEST.GETPARAMETER....THANKS FOR SPENDING UR VALUABLE TIME